# Counter to common believe, Carrier frequency dosn't have to be an odd multiple of fundmental frequency in 3 phase Inverters -- But Why?

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, inverter

According to Dr. Holmes book titled "Pulse Width Modulation for power converters" he states

> "First, the frequency of the .carrier harmonic is independent of the
> fundamental reference frequency, and hence always cancels between phase
> legs. Second, it is the "triplen multiple of n" sideband harmonics that cancel
> between the phase legs, with their frequencies matched irrespective of the
> absolute carrier frequency, and their phase shifts matched to the 1200 shift of
> the three-phase references (times the n multiple). With this understanding, it is
> clear that there is no particular benefit to be gained by a triplen carrier pulse
> ratio." page 253

However it is well documented in litereture that odd multiples of fundmental Harmonics do in fact have a performance benefits, and it can be confirmed by simulation. But to Dr.Holmes' defense the analytical expressions support his conclusion.

How do we reconciliate with the two opposing claims?

Comment: You can generate 3n harmonics without a 3n (or 3n * m) PWM carrier.

Comment: @user_1818839 yes, the point of interest is not triplen base-band harmonic as 3*n will cancel out in l-l 3phase outputs. But the argument is concerned with side-band harmonics around carrier frequencies. Many published literature advice for choosing the modulation index to be odd multiple of 3. This according to literature will chancel side-band harmonics. But the book I referenced shows the analytical solution of the pwm process and concludes that the suggestion that odd multiples of 3 has no performance benefits.